# Magento Multiple nodes maintenance mode(exam question)

Tags: magento2, certification, maintenance, loadbalancing, s3

> An Adobe Commerce Architect is working on a multi-server horizontally
> scaled Adobe Commerce on-premise installation. There are three nodes
> up and running the Adobe Commerce installation: node A, node B, and
> node C. A load balancer redirects traffic to each node evenly. The
> Remote Storage module is enabled and set up with a private S3 bucket
> to sync media between the nodes. The Architect wants to connect to the
> cluster by SSH and enable the maintenance mode through the
> `maintenance:enable` command. Which steps should the Architect take to
> make sure all servers go into maintenance mode?
>
> 1. Log in to one of the running nodes and run the `maintenance:enable` command. All nodes will then go into maintenance mode.
> 2. Log in to each node individually and run the `maintenance:enable` command on each individual node. The nodes will go into maintenance
>    one by one.
> 3. Create a custom remote storage for the `var/.maintenance.flag` file to get synchronized between the nodes. Then log in to one of the nodes
>    and run the `maintenance:enable` command. All nodes will then go into
>    maintenance mode.

This is an `AD0-E718 Adobe Commerce Architect Master` Sample Question and the correct answer provided by Adobe(no explanation) is `1`. But I think `3` is correct.

Can anybody tell me why `1` is correct?
Does the `remote-storage module` sync `var/.maintenance.flag` automatically, too?

Please also provide any **reference/documentation** if you can, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly have a look at `module-remote-storage/etc/di.xml`.

```
    ...
    <virtualType name="fullRemoteFilesystem" type="Magento\RemoteStorage\Filesystem" />
    ...
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">fullRemoteFilesystem</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

This means that when `magento/module-remote-storage` is enabled, the filesystem for MaintenanceMode is now also remote, hence synced up with all the nodes.